# Image from DB in Reporting Services

Tags: javascript, sql, image, reporting-services

**Essentially my problem at a basic level is I cannot get my images to display in SSRS.** I get the little box with an 'x' in it. These images are being **stored in a SQL db from a web app** that I've developed and have control over... getting handled by a web service I also have control over.

There are multiple spots I wonder if I have gone wrong:

**On the client** I use the javascript FileReader API to instantly render a thumbnail of an uploaded image for display to the user. `var reader = new FileReader();`

After calling `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` I put the data into a variable `imageURL = reader.result` and do some string operations to remove `data:image/jpeg;base64,` from the (base64 encoded) file data string, then eventually pass this variable to the server using a SOAP envelope.

So, **on the server** the image data is received by my web service (just a .asmx/not WCF) as a string datatype and then eventually inserted into the database as a SQL VARCHAR(MAX).

In **reporting services** I drop in an image control and set the image source to "database", the field to my photo field from my dataset and the MIME type to jpeg...which is all appropriate I believe.

So... I believe I am doing nothing wrong in SSRS but perhaps I am doing something wrong on the client in terms of how I'm sending the data?  OR Perhaps I am choosing to store my image data incorrectly. I do have access to the server machine, so maybe saving the images in the file system is what I need to do, but even still my current method seems like it should work.

Please let me know if I need to provide further information.

Comment: give some examples of the image url.

Comment: It's a long string so here's a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/r4qrY3Kz

Comment: I've utilized this tool to check for validity and always had a positive result: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to change your database field to be either:

- pre-SQL 2012 - image data type
- SQL 2012 - varbinary(max) as image data type has been depreciated

You'll also need to change your web service to upload a byte stream rather than a string.

Even if you're using SQL 2008 or 2008R2 I'd recommend you use the varbinary data type for future proofing of your database model.

To create a test data source for an SSRS report use the following SQL to generate a table entitled ImageTest. You'll need to supply the file path to an image which will be uploaded into the table.

```
CREATE TABLE ImageTest (
  image_data VARBINARY(MAX));

INSERT INTO ImageTest (image_data)
SELECT image_data
FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK N'<location of an image file>',
        SINGLE_BLOB) AS ImageSource(image_data);
```

To try out the table in SSRS create a new report with

- dataset pointing to the table ImageTest
- add an image control to the report and point its image source to the column image_data

When you preview the report you should see the report using your image stored in the database.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution.  Could you provide any documentation to further expand on your suggestion if possible?

Comment: Since you mention versions, I should say the DB is SQL 2010 and reporting services is also from VS 2010

Comment: The following article shows a simple .NET app for saving and loading images to SQL to give you an idea of the .NET code you might need to change. You'll hopefully find you've very little code to change.
[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437937/Save-and-Retrieve-Image-from-a-SQL-Server-Database)